# Styled Component - How to prevent a prop from being passed to the extended component?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am extending `Textarea` and I want `completed` to be accessed by `StyledItemTextarea` but not `Textarea`. How can I achieve this?

```
import Textarea from 'react-textarea-autosize';

const TextareaAutosizeSC = styled(Textarea)`
    ...
`;

const StyledItemTextarea = TextareaAutosizeSC.extend`
    color: ${({ completed }) => completed ? '#ccc' : '#fff'};
`;

const MyTextarea = ({ completed }) => <StyledItemTextarea completed={completed} />;
```

Comment: They have several solutions over here https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/305. Might help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
import Textarea from 'react-textarea-autosize';

const StyledItemTextarea = styled(({ completed, ...rest }) => <Textarea {...rest} />)`
    color: ${({ completed }) => completed ? '#ccc' : '#fff'};
`;

const MyTextarea = ({ completed }) => <StyledItemTextarea completed={completed} />;
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like this:

```
const TextareaAutosizeSC = ({ completed, ...rest }) => {
  const TextArea = styled(Textarea)`
    ...
  `;

  return <TextArea {...rest} />
}
```

or

```
const TextareaAutosizeSC = styled(Textarea)`
    ...
`;

const TextAreaWithoutSomeProps = ({ completed, ...rest }) => <TextareaAutosizeSC {...rest} />
```